# Return res.json is undefined in angular 2

Tags: angular

**When I'm calling getTasks function it returns Undefined in res.json**

tasks.service.ts

```
getTasks(){
        return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks')
        .map(res => {
            res.json()
        });
    }
```

tasks.component.ts

```
constructor(private _TaskService: TaskService){
        this._TaskService.getTasks()
        .subscribe(tasks =>{
            console.log(tasks);
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are not returning anything from the `map` function.

```
getTasks(){
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks')
    .map(res => {
        return res.json()
    });
}
```

or

```
getTasks(){
    return this._http.get('http://localhost:3000/api/tasks')
    .map(res => res.json());
}
```

Comment: in my case just the first hint did the fix. I had the 2nd option, but didn't work. why? I had: `getUsersList() {let obsUsersRequest = this.http.get(environment.urlUsers, this.options).map(res => {res.json();}).catch( ( error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') );return obsUsersRequest;}` which didn't work. Then I changed it to: `getUsersList() {let obsUsersRequest = this.http.get(environment.urlUsers, this.options) .map(res => {return res.json();}).catch( ( error: any) => Observable.throw(error.json().error || 'Server error') ); return obsUsersRequest;}`